# React + redux warning logic running after 60 seconds

Tags: reactjs, redux, countdown

The error is `warning: logic (L(COUNTDOWN_ADD)-1) is still running after 60s, forget to call done()? For non-ending logic, set warnTimeout: 0`

I am building a countdown, in which someone can input a start time and end time. This may be running for an hour -- any idea why this `console.log` message is appearing?

Answer (score 2):

This is intended behavior for v0.12. [See changelog](https://github.com/jeffbski/redux-logic#v012).

To fix it just do what error says - set `warnTimeout` to 0.

[Here is the example](https://github.com/jeffbski/redux-logic/blob/master/docs/api.md).

```
const fooLogic = createLogic({
  ...
  warnTimeout: 0, // default: 60000 (one minute)
})
```